# How to set Jenkins Job status based on Test Case Pass %

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

How to set Jenkins Job status based on Test Case Pass %.  I have a standalone job and would like to show the job status as passed when more than 80% test cases are passed. It's a testNG based framework.

Comment: Could you please provide more details of your job?